# Almost $\pi$: a closed form expression for $\int_0^\infty \left[ \left(1+\frac 1{x!}\right)^x-1\right] dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form

A slight variation of the famous limit definition of $e$ yields
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac 1 {n!}\right)^n =1.$$
By the comparison test, you can show that the series
$$ S= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ \left(1+\frac 1 {n!}\right)^n -1\right]$$
converges, and by the integral test, the corresponding integral
$$ I= \int_{0}^\infty \left[ \left(1+\frac 1 {\Gamma(x+1)}\right)^x-1\right] dx $$
converges as well.

> Are there closed-form expressions for the values of $S$ and $I$?

Approximate values are:
$$
\begin{split}
S &\approx 3.06768391298,\\
I &\approx 3.12609693980.
\end{split}
$$
This reminds me of the [Fransén-Robinson constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant), the integral of $1/\Gamma$ over $[0,\infty)$, being "almost" $e$, in the following way:
$$ F=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} + \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2+\ln^2(x)}dx.$$
I wonder whether $I-S \approx 0.05841302682$ can also be quantified as an improper integral of some sort.

Comment: It is amazing that both of them are between $3$ and $\pi$

Comment: Have you played around with the product definition of the gamma function? $$\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^z}{1+\frac{z}{n}}$$

Comment: @PopularPower I've been working on it

Comment: I doubt there exists closed form...

Comment: In the reciprocal gamma function integral. Appearance of $e$ can somewhat be intuitively seen, as $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{Γ\left(x\right)}\approx\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{Γ\left(n\right)}=e$$ But i fail to find a relationship between $\pi$ and your function (aside from the small numerical closeness though)

Comment: @Mourad Sorry, updated.